# If for each $x$ there is $b_i$ such that $\langle x,b_i\rangle\ne0$, then $\{b_i\}_I$ contains a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let there be a set $\{b_i\}_I$ in a Hilbert space $H$, such that 
$\forall x\in H\setminus\{0\} \exists b_i: \left< x,b_i\right>\ne0$.

How does this imply, that $\{b_i\}_I$ contains a basis?

It feels like this should be true.

Comment: I don't think it's true. Think about a sequence (1,1/4, 1/8, 1/16,....it's not a basis for l^2

Comment: You can use the hypothesis to find a maximal linearly independent, in particular orthogonal, subset of the $\{b_i\}.$ The non-zero condition suggests that this system is complete. Isn't any complete orthonormal system complete?

Comment: @Elad Sorry, I think I misunderstand what you are saying. Are you saying, that $\{(1,1/4, 1/8, 1/16,...)\}$ of satisfies the condition above? Because it certainly doesn't, see $x=(-4,1,0,0,...)$.

Comment: Yes I was careless sorry.

Comment: @Justin - $\{(0,1), (1,1)\}$ is such a set in the Hilbert space $\Bbb R^2$. Linearly independent you can get, but there is no guarantee of orthogonal.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Excellent point! I think I misread the statement and inferred some orthogonality condition.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 1):

Even though Justin was incorrect about orthogonality, his comment is right.

Choose a maximal linearly indepedent set of the $\{b_i\}$. In fact, you can define it as $\{b_i\mid b_i \notin \operatorname{span}(\{b_j\mid j < i\})\}$. For simplicity, re-index the reduced elements and call them $\{c_k\}$. Since $\{c_k\}$ is maximal, every $b_i$ is a linear combination of the $c_k$ - otherwise it could have been added to $\{c_k\}$ to form a larger linearly independent set. Because of this, you can show that $\{c_k\}$ also has the property that for all $x \ne 0$, there is some $k$ with $\langle x, c_k\rangle \ne 0$.

Perform Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to get orthonormal vectors $\{d_l\}$. The resulting vectors are linear combinations of the $\{c_k\}$, and vice-versa. They too satisfy the same property as $\{b_i\}$ and $\{c_k\}$.

Now consider the vector $x - \sum_l \langle x, d_l\rangle d_l$.

Comment: I think the issue is that the OP wanted to know if it contained a basis.

Comment: @Justin - I purposefully did not include the entire logic, just the road map. But everything to answer exactly that question is pointed to in this post. (Okay - I did leave the last turn off the list of directions as well, but I figured if he/she doesn't spot it anyway, I could point it out later.)

Comment: Of course, there are different approaches. For example, if $w \notin \operatorname{span}(\{b_i\})$, then you can find $u$ in the span so that $\|u-w\|$ is minimized, then show that necessarily $\langle u - w, b_i\rangle = 0$ for all $i$, contradicting the condition. Therefore $\{b_i\}$ spans the entire space and any maximal linearly independent subset must be a basis.